# Xpath expression to get a href description of a given class name

Tags: xpath, href

in this div class:

```
<div class="black">
<a href="/event.aspx?425627">Vitamin</a>
<a href="/club-detail.aspx?id=3213" title="Club profile of Watergate">Watergate</a>
</div>
```

I need an Xpath expression to get just the a href tag Description text, in this example "Vitamin" and "Watergate".

Comment: `Vitamin` : `/div/a[0]`, 


`Watergate` : `/div/a[1]`

Comment: Tnx, wich is for you the full Xpath expression to specify the div class?

Answer (score 1):

```
/div[@class='black']/a[0]/text()
```

will return Vitamin and

```
/div[@class='black']/a[1]/text()
```

will return Watergate.

Regards

You better google that first.

Comment: Thank you this is returning all the elements in the aa href tag...how can I get just the first? ( Vitamin in the example)

Comment: iv edited my answer, next time please add this term to the original question instead of create a comment, you can easyly edit your queston by press "edit" under your question.